# IPTV and NET over one cable - VLAN

Tags: switch, vlan

My scenario: House with 2 floors.

---

1st floor equipment:

- ONT (fixed on this floor) - with four ports - three for IPTV and one for Internet
- Netgear Switch GS105E
- NAS (fixed)
- Computer (fixed)

---

2nd floor:

- NetGear Switch GS108E
- WiFi Router Linksys E4200
- Settop box (fixed)
- Smart TV with LAN cable connection (fixed)
- Computer (fixed)

---

There is only **one** cable between the floors and there is no option to install another one.
My goal is to have STB receiving signal from ONT-IPTV and computers/NAS sharing Internet connection. 
I'm absolut newbie in NW, but I thought following setup could work:
1st floor switch ports:

1. Trunk cable - cable between floors
2. ONT - IPTV
3. ONT - Internet
4. NAS
5. Computer

2nd floor switch ports:

1. Trunk cable
2. STB
3. Router WAN
4. TV
5. Computer
6. Router LAN

VLAN config is the same for both floors (except 06/07/08 ports for the 1st floor):
`VLAN ID  | Port members:
     01       | 01 02
     02       | 01    03
     03       | 01      04 05 06 07 08`

Port 1 is marked as Tagged.

I thought this will do the magic, but I'm apparently doing something wrong. Internet is running fine, but TV is not.

Please help me to find a way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are 10base-t speeds acceptable for your needs? If so, perhaps a [CAT5 Y splitter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001H9AK1M) may solve your problem?

> CAT5 Y splitters let you connect 2 computers to 2 switch ports on your 10Mbps switch or hub through a single CAT5 patch cable. This is accomplished by utilizing a pair of normally unused wires found inside standard CAT5 Ethernet cables. It's like doubling a 10BASE-T network connection without pulling a new cable!Used in pairs, one adapter combines two 10BASE-T data signals at the wall jack; both signals are carried through one CAT5 network cable and a second adapter separates the signals allowing two connections at your 10Mbps hub or switch.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use this approach as it seems ONT is blocking packets from different MAC, but one from settobox.